# Where does Row Id come from when working the SQL connector of Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm executing a stored procedure using the On-Premise Data Gateway. The data returned is the following (obfuscated):

```
{
  "OutputParameters": {},
  "ResultSets": {
    "Table1": [
      {
        "SOPNUMBE": "string",
        "SYNCSTATUS3": "M",
        "Tracking_Number": "string",
        "OBJECTKEY": "2|string",
        "ScribeModifiedBy": "UPS",
        "ScribeModifiedDate": "2018-03-19T15:59:30.007"
      },
      {
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Nothing in there says to me "this is the Row Id".

Is this a limitation of working with on-prem SQL?

To provide some additional information, my stored procedure takes some information from dbo.SCRIBESHADOW and another table. I intend to update dbo.SCRIBESHADOW. Here is a screenshot from SSMS.

[image: dbo.SCRIBESHADOW key(s)]

Here are some sample rows. What would I put for the Row ID to update one of these rows?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by `Nothing in there says to me "this is the Row Id".` ? You have the result of the stored procedure ? if there is some missing fields, check your SP first

Comment: I mean I'm a novice and I've never heard the term "Row ID" until I started to use this connector. I amended my question some additional information.

Comment: From my understanding: you execute a stored procedure to get a list of rows. Then you want to use the `sql server - update row` action ? you need to define a primary key or a unique constraints on your table or you can use another stored procedure to update the row if you have a comnposite primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stored Procedure results do not have any Row ID because SP results are not table rows, even if the SP is composed of just one SELECT.  This is because the SP result is it's own table.

So, no, this isn't any limitation, it's just how Stored Procedures work.  If you need the RowID of any source table, you need to add it to the results.

To continue, if you need to Update a record based on the Stored Procedure results, then you will need to return from the SP the value of the Primary Key of the table you want to update.  That value is the Row id in the Update row Action.

However, if you are using a Stored Procedure to retrieve the data, you really should also be using a Stored Procedure to update the data.

Comment: I see what you're saying but I must be more ignorant on the topic that I previously thought. What is the Row ID? Is that the primary key? I've amended my question with some additional information.

Comment: I've been working on creating SPs for this and it's working well enough so far.